# iOS - Firebase Cloud Message without Notification

Tags: ios, swift

I followed the instruction from Firebase Cloud Message. However, I DO NOT want the application to show notification on the screen (both when the app is active or inactive), instead, the application will start the call (I already implemented my own CallKit). Can anyone give me a hint where can I modify the Appdelegate ? Please see my code below:

```
    // [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
```

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
```

}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: You can use silent notifications for that. They have a special structure and are not shown on UI. Or else as a workaround you can comment the completion handler line and the OS will not show the notification.

Comment: Hello @kapsym, thanks for reply. So, I need to comment out all 4 completionHandler for code snippets above right ? If that, you really save my day.

Comment: Have you considered using realtime database instead?

Comment: @le yes all completionHandler([])

Comment: MuhammadHassan thanks for advice. However, i don't need database for that.
@kapsym thanks a lot

Comment: @LeTrongTriet Let me know if it worked as per your requirement. I will then add it as an answer

Comment: @kapsym hi, i tested for over 2 weeks and notifications are still showing.